# How can I prohibit network users from accessing other user's home folders using Server permissions?

Tags: macos, permission, server.app

I have a 10.8 server, network users on a shared drive 'User Data' - used as a AFP for home folders, OD is on. All users are part of a group 'students 2013/14'.

My network user can login via OD over a network, however the permissions are not set correctly, since network user accounts can access all other users folder read/write on the sharepoint.

Question:
How can I set the permissions in Server.app correctly so that network users can login, use their server based home folder w/r but not access other network user home folders using the student 2013/14 group?

Comment: It may help to provide a screenshot of what your User Data share permissions look like.

Answer (score -2):

1. Launch Server.app
2. Click "File Sharing."
3. Click "Users."
4. Use Minus Sign to Remove Certain Users from Certain Folders.

Comment: This is a poor answer, my question is how I can set the group to have access to the shared users folder, its own users folder with read/write but not other users folders. As in; read and write to the root but not use inheritance for the other sub folders.